# same RMS error for different resolution data

Tags: erdas-imagine

if i rectify a low resolution data and high resolution data and both have same RMS error =1 then what would be rectify more accurately? means for which resolution this error is more acceptable comparatively to other ?

Answer (score 1):

The relationship is an inverse one. For example, if you have a 1 m error in a 30 m pixel, the percentage of error is much smaller than if you have a 1 m error in a 15 m pixel.

Comment: yes in case of meters but we calculate errors in pixel size on raw data then i think high resolution data is better rectified   make me correct if i am wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, not really clear on what you're asking here. Are you concerned with which image you should rectify or which image will rectify most accurately? If the latter, my original answer still holds.

Comment: i am  concerned with unrectified image means the image on which i want to apply rectification. and i am considering value of RMSE in Pixel unit of unrectified image.